# Login and then checkout PHP

Tags: php, html, authentication

When a person logs in, it directs them to the index.php band lets them checkout on my checkout page. When i change where i am directing them when they click login it doesnt work, then when they go to check out it keeps asking them to login. Anyone know where i may be going wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
 <head>  
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
 </head>  
 <body>  
 <div id="main">
 <?php
 include "base.php"; 
 if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Email']))
 {
      ?>

     <h1>Member Area</h1>
        <p>Thanks for logging in! Your email address is: <b><?=$_SESSION['Email']?><b> 

     <ul>
          <li><a href="logout.php">Logout.</a></li>
     </ul>

      <?php
  }
  elseif(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
 {
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['email']);
     $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['password']));

     $checklogin = mysqli_query($_SESSION['base'], "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email =   '".$email."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

     if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
     {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($checklogin);
            $email = $row['Email'];

         $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
         $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

     }
     else
      {
         echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
         echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
     }
 }
 else
 {     
    ?>

    <h1>Member Login</h1>

    <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>

     <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
     <fieldset>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />   <br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"     id="password" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
         </fieldset>
         </form>

    <?php
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is the base.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 $dbhost = "localhost"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
 $dbname = "Abandoned"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
 $dbuser = "root"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database
 $dbpass = ""; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database
 $base = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); if (!$base){
            echo "<p>server connection error:
 mysqli_connect_error()</p>";
 }
 $_SESSION['base'] = $base; //database connection status transfer;
 ?>
```

Comment: I believe you need `session_start()` to be in both or all PHP files and possibly a `session_destroy()` when user logs out.

Comment: Ok, does the inclusion of the base.php with session_start(); at the beginning not automatically include session start on every page where base.php is included?

Comment: Probably if `session_start()` is in your `base.php` file, however sometimes this may not be the case. Personally and on some occasions, I put it in all (PHP) files. You would have to try out different combinations. But for the most part, it must be in all PHP files.

Comment: @Fred If session_start() is in base.php, it still won't work, simply because he has sent HTML to the browser before calling it.

Comment: @CameronLaird See Wayne's answer below. He has put `base.php` over top HTML. Try that and see.

Comment: It works but when i change "<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">" to "<form method="post" action="phptests/shopping/index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">" it doesnt work

Comment: @CameronLaird check your paths to see if anything's not being ignored/excluded. Have you tried it with your original `action=index.php` call before using `phptests/shopping/index.php`?

Comment: Try adding a `session_id('session_name');` or `if(isset($_SESSION['session_name']))` - `session_name` being the name of session itself. There are 3 different sessions names that I've counted. Other than that, I don't know why it's not working for you. Someone with a higher degree of experience will have to tackle it on.

Answer (score 1):

To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.
ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

To fix this, you can move
`include "base.php";` 
to before your first line of html

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
 <head>  
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
 </head>  
 <body>  
 <div id="main">
 <?php
 include "base.php";
```

to

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
 <head>  
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
 </head>  
 <body>  
 <div id="main">
```

Bear in mind that I am making the assumption that session_start() is in your base.php file. If it isn't, it probably should be :) session_start() needs to be run before any output / headers. Without it, your sessions won't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. It still doesn't seem to be working. Should the session_start(); in every page?

Comment: @CameronLaird Yes. You should use session_start() on every page that your user will have access to.

Comment: It works but when i change "<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">" to "<form method="post" action="phptests/shopping/index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">" it doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" What is happening as opposed to what you expect to be happening?

Comment: When it has just index in it displays a blank page upon login and then you can add to basket and checkout, but when i change it, it goes to the right page but when i check out it keeps asking me to log in.

Comment: @CameronLaird You should and if possible, edit your question then add the entire codes. Minus username and password of course ;)